# failure to install lubuntu16.04 on toshiba-nb250

Tags: boot, iso, upload

I have tried to install with both usb and DVD that I had burned iso to. I keep getting message "graphics initialization failed  Error setting up gfxboot"  I had previously erased all on drive to get a single partition 145GB. This i had formatted to ext4. Tried to type "help" and "f1" as directed on internet advice, but no success.  Thanking you for assistance.